# jQuery dialog box not responding in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, dialog

First thing I have all the proper files on page; I tested it using a simple dialog confirmation page. What I am trying to do is load my partial view inside a dialog box once a button is clicked and nothing happens, I put a breakpoint on the partial view and it didn't go off either so the code must not be firing here is what I got

Main page

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 800,
      height: 400,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).load("/profile/edit");
      }
    });

    $('#my-button').click(function () {
      $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="my-button">Open Dialog</button>
```

And here is the partial view that I am trying to load

```
public PartialViewResult Edit() {
  return PartialView("_pedit");
}
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong; I have even tried to do this

```
$(this).load('@Url.Action("Edit","profile")');
```

and I know I got all the right files in place because if I put in the original Jquery code for the dialog box then it works which is

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       show: {
         effect: "blind",
         duration: 1000
       },
       hide: {
         effect: "explode",
         duration: 1000
       }
     });
     $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
     });
   });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
     <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information..</p>
   </div>
   <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
 </body>
```

Comment: Put breakpoint on public PartialViewResult Edit() and see whether control is coming over there or not????

Comment: yes I put a breakpoint,it didn't go through but I finally solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have used `$('#dialog').dialog`. So there should be a element with id `dialog` to load the content.

Add following `div` to your `view` and check.

`<div id="dialog"></div>`

Thanks!